# if/else statement stays in the first condition

Tags: if-statement

No matter the weight I enter, the output is always $3.50; however, it does not make any mistake on java. Can someone tell me what's wrong with it? Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Z8j.png)

Comment: Please add code as text to the question.

Comment: `weight > 0 || weight <= 1` will always be true. try `weight > 0 && weight <= 1` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the first condition `weight > 0` is always fulfiled.